# How install Ubuntu on already existing Ubuntu partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a laptop running Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 but I have issues with installing programs in Ubuntu and the only option is to reinstall. I do not want to format my laptop, i.e. my Windows 8 should stay.

My desire is to install Ubuntu afresh on the partition where it is now without further partitioning. How do I install over the existing installation?

This question was flagged a duplicate but I the other post on a similar did not address my issue.

Sorry for the confusion guys. The link was really helpful.

many thanks.

Comment: How does it not address your issue? Seems to answer it just fine.

Comment: If it doesn't you must explain "how so".

Answer (score 0):

- Boot ubuntu installation disk,and run `install ubuntu` option.
- Select `something else` option to manually  select the partition where you are going to install ubuntu.
- Select the already installed `ubuntu 12.10` partition and format it to `ext4` filesystem.
- Then choose the same formatted partition,to `install or reinstall` ubuntu.